# Isometry $\tau:V \to V$, not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

On p. 326 of Roman's *Advanced Linear Algebra*, 3rd edition, he says:

> It's easy to see that an isometry $\tau:V\to W$ is always injective,
>   but need not be surjective, even if $V=W$.

I'm looking for an example where $V=W$ and it is not surjective, but haven't thought of one. Does anyone have a thought?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that for any finite-dimensional vector space $V$, a transformation $\tau:V \to V$ will be injective if and only if it is surjective (by the dimension theorem).

With that in mind, let's take a suitable infinite-dimensional example.

Let $V$ be the space of infinite sequences $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ (or $x_i \in \mathbb{C}$, if you prefer) for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2 < \infty$.  We define the norm on $V$ via the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i \overline{y_i}$. Define
$$
\tau[(x_1,x_2,\dots)] = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)
$$
This example is often referred to as the right-shift operator.  Note that it is indeed an isometry on $V$ that is injective, but not surjective.

Comment: @rschwieb I am sending the sequence $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ to the sequence $\{0,x_1,x_2,\dots\}$.  The only sequence that gets mapped to $0 = \{0,0,\dots\}$ is $0 =\{0,0,\dots\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh, I interpreted that as a basis because of the braces... If the would have been parentheses I woulda seen it right away. Thanks!

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.  Conventions differ, but if braces are reserved for sets the parentheses ultimately make more sense.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. I'd be interested to know if anyone had other examples. :)

Comment: @EricAuld for other examples, I guess you'd have to look for any isometries on infinite-dimensional normed vector spaces.  Keep in mind that these can get weird; my example happens to be a Hilbert space (i.e. has an inner product), which makes it more intuition-friendly.  Try looking for something on $L^2([0,1])$ for another.

Comment: I am here in search of an element in codomain of V whose pre-image is not in domain V for $\tau:V \to V$ above so that I can show that $\tau$ is not surjective

Comment: @KavitaSahu take $x = (1,0,0,\dots)$

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Sorry why would the set $x={1,0,0,0,....} $suggest its not surjective?

Comment: @JerryCohen $x = (1,0,0,\dots)$ is an **element** of $V$. In particular, it is an element for which the equation $T(v) = x$ has no solution for $v \in V$.