# Show that $f$ is an isometry for infinite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry, automorphism-group

$V$ is a real vector-space and $f: V \rightarrow V $ an automorphism. Show that $f$ is an isometry iff $f^* = f^{-1}$.

This has been explained in our textbook for finite-dimensional situations however the exam question demands proof without using the textbook explanations which has left me stumped on how to approach this. Does anyone have a tip where to start with this proof? How does the dimension affect this so dramatically?

EDIT: 
For the ones asking what the course note proof is:

$\langle v, f^{*}(v) \rangle = \langle f(v), v \rangle = \langle f(v), f(f^{-1}(v))\rangle = \langle v, f^{-1}(v)\rangle$

Which implies $f^{*}=f^{-1}$

Comment: For the concept of isometry you need a distance function, a real vector space does not allow such a concept without additional structure. Are you assuming a Euclidean vector space (i.e. one with a scalar product)?

Comment: Unless we know that $V$ is finite dimensional, it is possible to have an isometry $f$ for which no inverse $f^{-1}$ exists.  See for instance [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/838901/81360)

Comment: @Thomas a Euclidean vector space is a finite one and the question explicitly is forbidding me to use the assumption of a finite-dimension so I'm sadly going to say no as much as I agree with your statement. That's why I am surprised at this exam question.

Comment: If you are looking for a different approach then the one followed in your course notes, can you maybe say how it is proven in the course notes?

Comment: Edited the question to provide the course notes explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $V$ is an inner product space with a norm defined by $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle}$, we can proceed as follows.

Firstly, assume $f^*=f^{-1}$. Then for any $x \in V$,
$$\lVert fx \rVert^2 = \langle fx, fx\rangle = \langle f^*fx, x\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle = \lVert x \rVert^2. $$
Secondly suppose that $f$ is an isometry. Then it preserves the inner product 
(since $\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(\lVert x + y\rVert^2 - \lVert x\lVert^2 - \lVert y\lVert ^2\right)$.
Therefore,
$$\langle x,y \rangle = \langle fx, fy \rangle=\langle f^*fx,y\rangle,$$
for all $x,y \in V$, from which it follows that $f^*f = \operatorname{id}$, thus $f^*=f^{-1}$. Note that the last step assumes that $f$ we already know $f$ is invertible.

If we do not assume that $f$ was invertible, and if the vector space is infinitedimensional, we cannot conclude from $f^*f=\operatorname{id}$ that $f$ is invertible.

I don't know in what sense you could consider this proof different from your textbook proof. It's certainly longer and very similar.